# Are there some properties like 'flex' for vertically according in extjs4?

Tags: layout, extjs4

In extjs4, 'flex' is used to flex items for horizontally according.

```
items:[
    {text: 'item1', flex: 1},
    {text: 'item2', flex: 1}
]
```

Are there some properties for vertically according too?

Answer (score 0):

The flex option is used in vertical box layouts (like vbox) similar to the way it is used in horizontal layouts (like hbox). With the difference that it is used for vertical flexing, even so the API documentation said otherwise. (It's just a flaw in the documentation).